# CSS float for HTML5 not floating video elements in div container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a full width HTML5 video slider/carousel thing. I've scoured the web and can't find one so I figured I'll try to make one my self.

Already I'm experiencing issues where it should be simple. I'm trying to float the videos next to each other so I could slide them in. For some reason, my videos don't want to listen to me. Here's my code.

css

```
.slider{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider .slide{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.15;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.slider .slide.active{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}
```

html - 5 slides in the mix

```
<div class="slider">

    <div class="slide active">
        <a href="/1.html" class="headerVideoLink">
            <video muted>
                <source src="/videos/trucks-driving.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href="/2.html" class="headerVideoLink">
            <video muted>
                <source src="/videos/money-moving.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href="/3.html" class="headerVideoLink">
            <video muted>
                <source src="/videos/trucks-driving.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href="/4.html" class="headerVideoLink">
            <video muted>
                <source src="/videos/globe-spinning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href="/5.html" class="headerVideoLink">
            <video muted>
                <source src="/videos/arrow-target.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </a>
    </div>

</div><!-- slider -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of floating elements is related to the space (width) provided by the parent. In your case, they both have the same width (100%). This explains the line break.

To avoid line breaks, the right CSS property to use is `word-break: keep-all;`
But this can not work with floating elements.

Best solution is to used `display: inline-block` property for `.slide`, and `white-space: nowrap;` for `.slider`

Major problem of inline-block is the additional space triggered usually by HTML code indentation itself. One good solution is to add a `font-size: 0` to the parent. In your case, this should not be a problem as you display videos.

**CSS**

```
.slider{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider .slide{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.15;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.slider .slide.active{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}
```